P value line comparing two columns
I need to creat one line above my two columns graph comparing the p value (found on my chi squared test). I need help creating a simple code to add on my graph code.
i used the ggstatsplot
my code:
test <- chisq.test(table(data_xxxx$yyyy_tipo, data_xxxx$zzzz))

ggbarstats(data_xxxx, zzzz, yyyy_tipo,results.subtitle = FALSE, perc.k = 2,subtitle = paste0("Fisher's exact test", ", p-value = ",ifelse(test$p.value < 0.0001, "< 0.0001",round(test$p.value, 3)))) +

scale_fill_manual(values = c("yes" = "khaki", "no" = "mediumpurple3")) +

xlab("Presença de trauma") +

ylab("Apresentação do TDAH") +

guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Tipo de Trauma"))`

I also tried:
  data = data_di,
  x = grupo,
  y = t_inter,
  results.subtitle = TRUE,  
  perc.k = 2
) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yes" = "khaki", "no" = "mediumpurple3")) +  # Personalizar cores
  labs(title = "Distribuição de Internalizantes por Grupo", x = "Grupo", y = "Frequência") +
  theme_classic()  

# Adicionar a linha comparativa com o valor de p usando qui-quadrado
grafico <- grafico +
  geom_signif(
    comparisons = list(c("limitrofe", "tdi")),  corretos
    map_signif_level = TRUE, 
    test = "chisq.test",  
    textsize = 3.5
  )

# Exibir o gráfico
print(grafico)```

but on this one there's no p value line comparing my two columns and also it's all grey, when i clered wanted it with other colors

Like this horizontal line:
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/WxkhuLgw.png

